# JavaScript modified some value in original JSON

Tags: javascript

I have:

```
const parsedData = [
  { id: 1, key: 'asdas'},
  { id: 2, key: 'asdas'},
]
parsedData.map((item, i) => ({
  ...item,
  key: `modified ${item.key}`
}));
console.log(parsedData);
```

What I'm trying is to get `parsedData` array modified and get:

```
[
  { id: 1, key: 'modified asdas'},
  { id: 2, key: 'modified asdas'},
]
```

But I'm getting the same array in the console.log

Comment: `map` returns a new array, it doesn't modify the existing one. Try `const modified = parsedData.map( ... )` instead.

Comment: Yes, if we print the result of map method it works

Comment: The [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is pretty clear on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` returns the modified array; it does not mutate the original.

You should be logging the result returned by `map`:

```js
const parsedData = [
  { id: 1, key: 'asdas'},
  { id: 2, key: 'asdas'},
]
let res = parsedData.map((item, i) => ({
  ...item,
  key: `modified ${item.key}`
}));
console.log(res);
```

Alternatively, you can use `forEach`:

```js
const parsedData = [
  { id: 1, key: 'asdas'},
  { id: 2, key: 'asdas'},
]
parsedData.forEach((item, i) => (parsedData[i] = {
  ...item,
  key: `modified ${item.key}`
}));
console.log(parsedData);
```

Answer (score 1):

a map will return a new array you need to capture it in different variable

```
const parsedData = [
  { id: 1, key: 'asdas'},
  { id: 2, key: 'asdas'},
]

const newData = parsedData.map((item, i) => ({
  ...item,
  key: `modified ${item.key}`
}));

console.log(newData);
```